# How to subtract two time stamps along with their dates in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a two variables :

```
A= 04.07.2019 23:29:40
B= 05.07.2019 01:15:52
```

I want to perform a arithmetic operation `C = A - B` using bash.

Can some one help me in converting them into integers. In general the dates are different every time, that is why cant neglect the dates.

Output should be in seconds/minutes. If possible in `HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: In what format do you want C? Will seconds be okay?

Comment: Yes, it should be in seconds/minutes.

Comment: You can use `date`to convert each date to seconds since epoc, subtract them and the convert the resulting seconds back to HH:MM:SS. See `man date` on howto specify date formats, or convert the date format so that date command understands it natively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `date` to convert to timestamp which is seconds, subtract the seconds and then convert back to `HH:MM:SS`.

Unfortunately, `date` doesn't read the specified format, so we need to turn around the `DD.MM.YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```bsh
{
A="04.07.2019 23:29:40"
B="05.07.2019 01:15:52"

# Create a function to change DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
convert_date(){ printf '%s-%s-%s %s' ${1:6:4} ${1:3:2} ${1:0:2} ${1:11:8}; }

# Convert to timestamp
A_TS=$(date -d "$(convert_date "$A")" +%s)
B_TS=$(date -d "$(convert_date "$B")" +%s)

# Subtract
DIFF=$((B_TS-A_TS))

# convert to HH:MM:SS (note, that if it's more than one day, it will be wrong!)
TZ=UTC date -d @$DIFF +%H:%M:%S
}
```

Output:

```
01:46:12
```

---

Using a more general function to subtract the dates:

```bsh
diff_dates(){
    TS1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
    TS2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
    [ $TS2 -ge $TS1 ] \
        && TZ=UTC date -d @$((TS2-TS1)) +%H:%M:%S \
        || TZ=UTC date -d @$((TS1-TS2)) +-%H:%M:%S
}

convert_date(){
    printf '%s-%s-%s %s' ${1:6:4} ${1:3:2} ${1:0:2} ${1:11:8};
}
```

Usage:

```
$ A="04.07.2019 23:29:40"
$ B="05.07.2019 01:15:52"
$ diff_dates "$(convert_date "$A")" "$(convert_date "$B")"
01:46:12
```

or if you already have `date`-compatible dates:

```
$ diff_dates "2019-07-04 23:29:40" "2019-07-05 01:15:52"
01:46:12
$ diff_dates "2019-07-05 01:15:52" "2019-07-04 23:29:40"
-01:46:12
```

Comment: If possible, can you explain how this line is working: convert_date(){ printf '%d-%d-%d %s' ${1:6:4} ${1:3:2} ${1:0:2} ${1:11:8}; }

Comment: `convert_date(){...}` creates a [function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) .`$1` is the first argument in the function `${1:6:4}` is named [parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) and will cut 4 characters  starting with position 6 => "YYYY" and the others equivalently. `'%d-%d-%d %s'` is the output format for `printf`.

Comment: Getting this error: 
> convert_date(){ printf '%d-%d-%d %s' ${1:6:4} ${1:3:2} ${1:0:2} ${1:11:8}; }
# Convert to timestamp
> TDS_TS=$(date -d "$(convert_date "$TDS")" +%s)
> TDE_TS=$(date -d "$(convert_date "$TDE")" +%s)
 }
-bash: printf: 09: invalid octal number
date: invalid date ‘2019-7-0 21:44:08’
-bash: printf: 09: invalid octal number
date: invalid date ‘2019-7-0 22:06:14’
01:00:00

Comment: hm, you might use `%s` instead of `%d`, might be it has problems with leading zero, please see my change ?!

Comment: Perfect!! I really thank you. Hope will learn it soon like you :)

Comment: it prints `03:46:12` in my case

Comment: interesting thing is that 2:46:52 is wrong, it must be 1:46:52 and no one noticed :-D I'll fix

Comment: here you go ... now it should be correct. Problem was: `date -d @3600 +%H` vs `TZ=UTC date -d @3600 +%H`

Comment: It works now. Thanks.